# Extending JSF validation in application

Tags: validation, jsf

We are developing a web application based on JSF (v2.0) framework. We need to have custom validations in our application. We decided to extend the `JSF validation framework` by implementing the `Validator` class.

So let us say that we have multiple input fields which needs to be validated. These input fields are `First Name, Last Name`, `Email Address.` We need the user to enter information in these fields. And email address field will have two validations - `Required` and `isValidEmailAddress`.

We should be able to use the custom `Required` validation in `First Name, Last Name` and `Email Address` fields. **But each time I want different error messages to be displayed for each field**. For example in case of `First Name`, I want to display First Name`is required. In case of`Last name`I want to display`Last name is required`.

How can I reuse the same `Required` validation implementation for multiple fields but with different error message? Is it possible to do that in JSF? Could you please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need to write your own validation logic for required input in JSF. It's one of the basic amenities provided by the framework itself.

JSF's validation framework is cleanly abstracted from messages related to validation, so the two don't have to depend on each other. Your options:

1. Each input component has a `validatorMessage` attribute that allows you specify the text/string that will be displayed to the user on validation error. For your specific use case, JSF has gone one step further to specify the `required` and `requiredMessage` attribute for input components; to enforce required input and show messages specifically for required input validation respectively. What this means in your use case is that you don't need to write custom validation logic for required input.
2. By principle of better design you can configure all your desired validation/conversion error messages in a resource bundle (example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-and-resource-bundles-example/)) and reference the entries in the resource bundle within your jsf view.

Implementing the validator interface requires you implement the `validate` method with the following signature

```
   public void validate(FacesContext ctxt, UIComponent comp, Object value) throws ValidatorException
```

`comp` refers to the component being validated from which you can get it's `Class`, clientId etc. `value` will provide the submitted value from the component

Comment: We cannot use the resource bundle since we decided to keep all the messages in DataBase so that it can be changed easily (no deployment needed). Even the "requiredMessage" can it be derived programmatically rather than hard-coding?

Comment: @Apps Caution: Elements such as error/warning messages are best consumed from a static source. You don't want a trip to the database for everytime someone screws up an entry in a webform. Having said that, you could just load all the messages into an ApplicationScoped bean and reference it's member variables (corresponding to String type messages) within the attributes. You simply implement the logic for the loading the messages (from DB,WS,file etc) within the application scoped bean

Comment: Thanks Kolossus. Even though it is stored in databases, we will store the information in application scope after the first time it is retrieved from DB. In all subsequent requests, it will be served from application scope. Can we use the Validator interface and have different error messages for each component?

Comment: @Apps yes you can. Like I stated in my answer, each component carries it's own `validatorMessage` attribute in which you can define a text to be displayed for only that component's validation error

Comment: thanks. But how do I make a Custom Validation implementation generic with different messages for each component? Is it possible to pass some custom attributes from the client which tells the Custom Validation implementation that this the error message key which needs to be used?

Comment: @Apps, yes you can. The implementation of validator interface supplies the component that is being validated as an argument which you can interrogate for parameters that you will use to customize the validation. I've updated the answer